# Cannot add category to AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, categories, avfoundation

I'm trying to add a category to AVAudioPlayer but I keep getting the error "Cannot find interface declaration for 'AVAudioPlayer'".

**AVAudioPlayer+Fade.h**

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface AVAudioPlayer (Fade)

- (void)fadeToVolume:(CGFloat)volume;

@end
```

**AVAudioPlayer+Fade.m**

```
@implementation AVAudioPlayer (Fade)

- (void)fadeToVolume:(CGFloat)volume
{
}

@end
```

I'm using an AVAudioPlayer in my `MainMenuViewController` class, so I added:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

to `MainMenuViewController.h`

and I added:

```
#import "AVAudioPlayer+Fade.h"
```

to `MainMenuViewController.m`.

The AVFoundation is added to the project. I can use the AVAudioPlayer perfectly without the Fade category. When I add the Fade category, I get that error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that you need to add `#import "AVAudioPlayer+Fade.h"` to **AVAudioPlayer+Fade.m**.